# IOS Build OptionSetting for Xamarin.Forms(IOS)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

We are getting Exception when we are setting IOS (Advance)Build option
SSL/TLS implementation to Mono(TVS v1.0) or Apple TLS(default).

Which one is recommended

Thanks in Advance
cheers:)

Comment: Can you add the `Exception` to your question. Due to the fact that Apple TLS supports versions 1.0, 1.1, & 1.2, personally I would use it over Mono's managed TLS 1.0 provider unless you have legacy code that is dependent on Mono's implementation. Note: In the latest Xamarin.iOS releases the *outdated* Mono managed provider has been removed in favor of using the Apple TLS provider

Comment: We are using Apple TLS build option but we are getting Exception: System.Net.WebExceptionError: ConnectFailure (Connection refused).      Do you know any workaround so I won't get an exception while using Apple TLS ?..... Thanks in Advance  @SushiHangover